# Is it possible to hash using MD5 in BigQuery?

Tags: md5, google-bigquery

Does BigQuery have MD5() functionality?  I know it has cityhash but I need MD5 specifically. thanks!

Comment: @dcsohl due to legacy systems support requirement it would be very nice to have md5 built-in function. We used this MySQL and postgress function before and need a simple way to support/emulate it in BigQuery.

Answer (score 8):

Since this shows up in Google searches for "BigQuery MD5", for instances, it's worth pointing out that BigQuery supports the following hashing functions natively in [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#hash-functions):

- MD5
- SHA1
- SHA256
- SHA512

Comment: Thanks! These seem to return base64 rather than hex. Do you know how I could convert it?

Comment: There's a [feature request that you can follow](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62599093) and it has a workaround, too. Does that help?

Comment: (And as an update, there is a `TO_HEX` function now that lets you convert bytes to hex).

Answer (score 3):

No, but bigquery does have some sha1-hash support. The `SHA1()` function returns bytes, but you can convert this to base64 by using `TO_BASE64()` which will give you a nice string or `STRING()` which will give you an ugly one:

```
SELECT TO_BASE64(SHA1(corpus)) from [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] limit 100;
```

Comment: is there any update on state of supporting functions like sha1(), to_base64(), etc.? Are they expected to be supported? I havent found them in documentation. What are other available? Thank you!

Comment: I am not aware of any publicly documented progress for either the TO_BASE64, SHA1 functions.

There is however, this [Issue 175](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=175#c4) which states that we can expect TO_BASE64 and FROM_BASE64 functions to be documented in the near future. No explicit timeline is mentioned.

I've found no issue regarding SHA1 or any other mention of it. Though all the functions mentioned in this comment work for me. That may change at any time though as state by Jordan.

No mention of MD5 nor is it a known function in BigQuery

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread here. It is now possible to implement md5 in BigQuery using user-defined functions: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions

Here is some example code:

```
function md5cycle(x, k) {
var a = x[0], b = x[1], c = x[2], d = x[3];

a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[0], 7, -680876936);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[1], 12, -389564586);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[2], 17,  606105819);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[3], 22, -1044525330);
a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[4], 7, -176418897);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[5], 12,  1200080426);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[6], 17, -1473231341);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[7], 22, -45705983);
a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[8], 7,  1770035416);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[9], 12, -1958414417);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[10], 17, -42063);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[11], 22, -1990404162);
a = ff(a, b, c, d, k[12], 7,  1804603682);
d = ff(d, a, b, c, k[13], 12, -40341101);
c = ff(c, d, a, b, k[14], 17, -1502002290);
b = ff(b, c, d, a, k[15], 22,  1236535329);

a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[1], 5, -165796510);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[6], 9, -1069501632);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[11], 14,  643717713);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[0], 20, -373897302);
a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[5], 5, -701558691);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[10], 9,  38016083);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[15], 14, -660478335);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[4], 20, -405537848);
a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[9], 5,  568446438);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[14], 9, -1019803690);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[3], 14, -187363961);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[8], 20,  1163531501);
a = gg(a, b, c, d, k[13], 5, -1444681467);
d = gg(d, a, b, c, k[2], 9, -51403784);
c = gg(c, d, a, b, k[7], 14,  1735328473);
b = gg(b, c, d, a, k[12], 20, -1926607734);

a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[5], 4, -378558);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[8], 11, -2022574463);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[11], 16,  1839030562);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[14], 23, -35309556);
a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[1], 4, -1530992060);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[4], 11,  1272893353);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[7], 16, -155497632);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[10], 23, -1094730640);
a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[13], 4,  681279174);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[0], 11, -358537222);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[3], 16, -722521979);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[6], 23,  76029189);
a = hh(a, b, c, d, k[9], 4, -640364487);
d = hh(d, a, b, c, k[12], 11, -421815835);
c = hh(c, d, a, b, k[15], 16,  530742520);
b = hh(b, c, d, a, k[2], 23, -995338651);

a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[0], 6, -198630844);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[7], 10,  1126891415);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[14], 15, -1416354905);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[5], 21, -57434055);
a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[12], 6,  1700485571);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[3], 10, -1894986606);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[10], 15, -1051523);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[1], 21, -2054922799);
a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[8], 6,  1873313359);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[15], 10, -30611744);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[6], 15, -1560198380);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[13], 21,  1309151649);
a = ii(a, b, c, d, k[4], 6, -145523070);
d = ii(d, a, b, c, k[11], 10, -1120210379);
c = ii(c, d, a, b, k[2], 15,  718787259);
b = ii(b, c, d, a, k[9], 21, -343485551);

x[0] = add32(a, x[0]);
x[1] = add32(b, x[1]);
x[2] = add32(c, x[2]);
x[3] = add32(d, x[3]);

}

function cmn(q, a, b, x, s, t) {
a = add32(add32(a, q), add32(x, t));
return add32((a << s) | (a >>> (32 - s)), b);
}

function ff(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn((b & c) | ((~b) & d), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function gg(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn((b & d) | (c & (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function hh(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn(b ^ c ^ d, a, b, x, s, t);
}

function ii(a, b, c, d, x, s, t) {
return cmn(c ^ (b | (~d)), a, b, x, s, t);
}

function md51(s) {
txt = '';
var n = s.length,
state = [1732584193, -271733879, -1732584194, 271733878], i;
for (i=64; i<=s.length; i+=64) {
md5cycle(state, md5blk(s.substring(i-64, i)));
}
s = s.substring(i-64);
var tail = [0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0];
for (i=0; i<s.length; i++)
tail[i>>2] |= s.charCodeAt(i) << ((i%4) << 3);
tail[i>>2] |= 0x80 << ((i%4) << 3);
if (i > 55) {
md5cycle(state, tail);
for (i=0; i<16; i++) tail[i] = 0;
}
tail[14] = n*8;
md5cycle(state, tail);
return state;
}

/* there needs to be support for Unicode here,
 * unless we pretend that we can redefine the MD-5
 * algorithm for multi-byte characters (perhaps
 * by adding every four 16-bit characters and
 * shortening the sum to 32 bits). Otherwise
 * I suggest performing MD-5 as if every character
 * was two bytes--e.g., 0040 0025 = @%--but then
 * how will an ordinary MD-5 sum be matched?
 * There is no way to standardize text to something
 * like UTF-8 before transformation; speed cost is
 * utterly prohibitive. The JavaScript standard
 * itself needs to look at this: it should start
 * providing access to strings as preformed UTF-8
 * 8-bit unsigned value arrays.
 */
function md5blk(s) { /* I figured global was faster.   */
var md5blks = [], i; /* Andy King said do it this way. */
for (i=0; i<64; i+=4) {
md5blks[i>>2] = s.charCodeAt(i)
+ (s.charCodeAt(i+1) << 8)
+ (s.charCodeAt(i+2) << 16)
+ (s.charCodeAt(i+3) << 24);
}
return md5blks;
}

var hex_chr = '0123456789abcdef'.split('');

function rhex(n)
{
var s='', j=0;
for(; j<4; j++)
s += hex_chr[(n >> (j * 8 + 4)) & 0x0F]
+ hex_chr[(n >> (j * 8)) & 0x0F];
return s;
}

function hex(x) {
for (var i=0; i<x.length; i++)
x[i] = rhex(x[i]);
return x.join('');
}

function md5(s) {
return hex(md51(s));
}

function add32(a, b) {
return (a + b) & 0xFFFFFFFF;
}

var input_columns = ['value'];

var output_schema = [{name: 'md5', type: 'string'}];

bigquery.create_tvf(
   'md5',  // The function name exposed to Dremel.
   input_columns,
   output_schema,
   // This function will be invoked once for each input record.
   function(record, emit) {
   emit({md5: hex(md51(record.value))});
   }
);
```

Comment: We are heavily relying on JS UDF in implementing functions like this, SHA256 for example. The problem is - Google team aggressively labels such queries with high billing tiers. I hope this will be addressed at some point or otherwise JS UDF as they are today - are not much useful on big scale