# A fast, non secure database Hash function reproducible across Multiple databases

Tags: mysql, oracle, postgresql, hash, google-bigquery

Hello all :) I have a key that is present in several databases. I need a way to query for reproducible deterministic samplings on the keys; Consistently across Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, and BigQuery.

The hash does not need to be secure, but I need a good distribution.

The keys might not all be present on all sides, but I need to select them when they are. I can't rely on ORDER BY + LIMIT.

Here is an example, for when I need to work on a 10% sample of the dataset:

```
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE my_hash(key, 10) = 0
```

The key is in [A-Z0-9] varchar fixed length format (about 20 chars).

I am inclined to sum the ascii char int value progressively and multiplying by a prime at each step, but I feel this won't be very fast.

While each database has such a hash, they are incompatible (probably tied to the underlying implementation I suppose).

The SQL standard does not seem to define a hash :/

Versions are:

Postgres 9.4,
Oracle 10g,
MySQL 5.5.41

Comment: @joop MD5 is not available in bigquery http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394896/is-it-possible-to-hash-using-md5-in-bigquery. SHA1 is, but not in Oracle 10g

Answer (score 0):

Few options from BigQuery standpoint:

- There is a [HASH()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#otherfunctions) function in BigQuery (*defined by the CityHash
  library*)
- There is support for [User-Defined Functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/user-defined-functions) where with JavaScript you can implement any [hashing] algorithm, like MD5 for example.

Below is just quick example from my recent replies on other question

```
SELECT input, input_sha256 FROM JS(
(
  SELECT title AS input
  FROM [bigquery-public-data:hacker_news.stories]
  GROUP BY input
  LIMIT 40 
),
input,
"[ {'name': 'input', 'type': 'string'}, {'name': 'input_sha256', 'type': 'string'} ] ",

"function(row, emit) {   

  var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){var f={},g=f.lib={},q=function(){},m=g.Base={extend:function(a){q.prototype=this;var c=new q;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty('init')||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty('toString')&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}}, r=g.WordArray=m.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=s?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||k).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,d=a.words,b=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(b%4)for(var e=0;e<a;e++)c[b+e>>>2]|=(d[e>>>2]>>>24-8*(e%4)&255)<<24-8*((b+e)%4);else if(65535<d.length)for(e=0;e<a;e+=4)c[b+e>>>2]=d[e>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,d);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<< 32-8*(c%4);a.length=h.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],d=0;d<a;d+=4)c.push(4294967296*h.random()|0);return new r.init(c,a)}}),l=f.enc={},k=l.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++){var e=c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255;d.push((e>>>4).toString(16));d.push((e&15).toString(16))}return d.join('')},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b+=2)d[b>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(b, 2),16)<<24-4*(b%8);return new r.init(d,c/2)}},n=l.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++)d.push(String.fromCharCode(c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255));return d.join('')},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b++)d[b>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(b)&255)<<24-8*(b%4);return new r.init(d,c)}},j=l.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(n.stringify(a)))}catch(c){throw Error('Malformed UTF-8 data');}},parse:function(a){return n.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}}, u=g.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=m.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new r.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){'string'==typeof a&&(a=j.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var c=this._data,d=c.words,b=c.sigBytes,e=this.blockSize,f=b/(4*e),f=a?h.ceil(f):h.max((f|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=f*e;b=h.min(4*a,b);if(a){for(var g=0;g<a;g+=e)this._doProcessBlock(d,g);g=d.splice(0,a);c.sigBytes-=b}return new r.init(g,b)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this); a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});g.Hasher=u.extend({cfg:m.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){u.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new a.init(d)).finalize(c)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new t.HMAC.init(a, d)).finalize(c)}}});var t=f.algo={};return f}(Math);   

  (function(h){for(var s=CryptoJS,f=s.lib,g=f.WordArray,q=f.Hasher,f=s.algo,m=[],r=[],l=function(a){return 4294967296*(a-(a|0))|0},k=2,n=0;64>n;){var j;a:{j=k;for(var u=h.sqrt(j),t=2;t<=u;t++)if(!(j%t)){j=!1;break a}j=!0}j&&(8>n&&(m[n]=l(h.pow(k,0.5))),r[n]=l(h.pow(k,1/3)),n++);k++}var a=[],f=f.SHA256=q.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new g.init(m.slice(0))},_doProcessBlock:function(c,d){for(var b=this._hash.words,e=b[0],f=b[1],g=b[2],j=b[3],h=b[4],m=b[5],n=b[6],q=b[7],p=0;64>p;p++){if(16>p)a[p]= c[d+p]|0;else{var k=a[p-15],l=a[p-2];a[p]=((k<<25|k>>>7)^(k<<14|k>>>18)^k>>>3)+a[p-7]+((l<<15|l>>>17)^(l<<13|l>>>19)^l>>>10)+a[p-16]}k=q+((h<<26|h>>>6)^(h<<21|h>>>11)^(h<<7|h>>>25))+(h&m^~h&n)+r[p]+a[p];l=((e<<30|e>>>2)^(e<<19|e>>>13)^(e<<10|e>>>22))+(e&f^e&g^f&g);q=n;n=m;m=h;h=j+k|0;j=g;g=f;f=e;e=k+l|0}b[0]=b[0]+e|0;b[1]=b[1]+f|0;b[2]=b[2]+g|0;b[3]=b[3]+j|0;b[4]=b[4]+h|0;b[5]=b[5]+m|0;b[6]=b[6]+n|0;b[7]=b[7]+q|0},_doFinalize:function(){var a=this._data,d=a.words,b=8*this._nDataBytes,e=8*a.sigBytes; d[e>>>5]|=128<<24-e%32;d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+14]=h.floor(b/4294967296);d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+15]=b;a.sigBytes=4*d.length;this._process();return this._hash},clone:function(){var a=q.clone.call(this);a._hash=this._hash.clone();return a}});s.SHA256=q._createHelper(f);s.HmacSHA256=q._createHmacHelper(f)})(Math);   

  (function(){var h=CryptoJS,j=h.lib.WordArray;h.enc.Base64={stringify:function(b){var e=b.words,f=b.sigBytes,c=this._map;b.clamp();b=[];for(var a=0;a<f;a+=3)for(var d=(e[a>>>2]>>>24-8*(a%4)&255)<<16|(e[a+1>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+1)%4)&255)<<8|e[a+2>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+2)%4)&255,g=0;4>g&&a+0.75*g<f;g++)b.push(c.charAt(d>>>6*(3-g)&63));if(e=c.charAt(64))for(;b.length%4;)b.push(e);return b.join('')},parse:function(b){var e=b.length,f=this._map,c=f.charAt(64);c&&(c=b.indexOf(c),-1!=c&&(e=c));for(var c=[],a=0,d=0;d< e;d++)if(d%4){var g=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d-1))<<2*(d%4),h=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d))>>>6-2*(d%4);c[a>>>2]|=(g|h)<<24-8*(a%4);a++}return j.create(c,a)},_map:'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/='}})();   

  emit( { 
    input: row.input, 
    input_sha256: CryptoJS.SHA256(row.input).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex) 
  } ); 
}" 
)
```