# SHA_256 Hash in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, sha256

I am trying to find the SQL equivalent of hash in bigquery.

SQL :

```
 SELECT    CAST(HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', CONCAT(
                                            COL1, COL2, COL3
                                        )) AS BINARY(32)) AS HashValue
```

Big Query:

```
SELECT  SHA2_256(CONCAT(COL1, '', COL2 )) AS HashValue.
```

I can't find any examples where hashing is done on multiple columns. The datatype of the columns are different as well.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see follow this [change request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62599093)

> These are now implemented. Thanks again for sharing feedback on needing these ?> functions. Please see:
>
> TO_HEX: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#to_hex
>
> FROM_HEX: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#from_hex

2 related questions I found for you are:
[Is it possible to hash using MD5 in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23394896/1031958)
[Random Sampling in Google BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23375456/1031958)

Answer (score 1):

Using Standard SQL ([SHA256 function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/hash_functions#sha256)) you could cast all your fields to string, concatenate them and use the hash. Something like this:

```
SELECT SHA256( 
              CONCAT(
                  CAST(integer_field1 as STRING), 
                  CAST(integer_field2 as STRING), 
                  CAST(timestamp_field as STRING) 
                  )
         ) as sha256_hash FROM `table`
```